# Is there a way to query azure virtual networks for the next available subnet range

Tags: powershell, network-programming, azure-virtual-network

I have a virtual network (VNET) configured in azure with an address space of 10.0.0.0/8 that I'm using for a sort of (poor man's) IPAM functionality only.
I have several subnets configured in that NVET, 10.14.1.0/24, 10.14.2.0/24, 10.14.3.0/24, ...

What I want to do is query the NVET for the next available subnet "slot" (e.g. 10.14.12.0/24 is in use but 10.14.13.0/24 is not yet in use), and then store that "slot" as a variable and reserve it by creating the subnet with a given name.

```
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name IPAM-vnet
$sublist = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $vnet | Where-Object {$_.AddressPrefix -gt "10.14*"} | Sort-Object -Property AddressPrefix -Descending
$lastsub = $sublist[0].AddressPrefix

PS C:\> write-host $lastsub
10.14.12.0/24
```

How can I increment the 3rd octet in this string (10.14.**12**.0/24) to (10.14.**13**.0/24) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can get the third octet.

```
$template = @'
10.14.{third:12}.0/24
'@
$thirdoctet = '10.14.12.0/24' | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template | select -Expand third

$thirdoctet = if('10.14.12.0/24' -match '(\d{2,3})(?=.\d*\/24)'){$matches.1}

$thirdoctet = '10.14.12.0/24' -split '\.' | select -Skip 2 -First 1

get-variable thirdoctet

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
thirdoctet                     12
```

Now you can just add 1. However, since some of those are actually strings, you may end up with

```
 $thirdoctet + 1

 121
```

If you position the integer on the left hand side, it will coerce the right hand side to an integer as well, if it can.

```
$nextoctet = 1 + $thirdoctet
$nextoctet
13
```

Now you can just replace the octet

```
$newsubnet = $lastsub -replace $thirdoctet,$nextoctet
```

To increment and end up with the desired string in one go, I'd use the regex method

```
$newsubnet = $lastsub -replace '(\d{2,3})(?=.\d*\/24)',(1+$matches.1)
get-variable newsubnet

Name                      Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                          -----                                                                                                                                                          
newsubnet              10.14.13.0/24
```